# Want to return list from repository to viewmodel MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project where i hava to fetch the data from firestore in a repository and then return it to viewmodel and from viewmodel to activity/fragment but the loop return the list before the data getting fetched

my activity code

```
 binding!!.mainspinnercatalog.onItemSelectedListener =
        object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                p0: AdapterView<*>?,
                p1: View?,
                position: Int,
                p3: Long
            ) {
                val mainCatalog = p0?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

                addNamesViewModel.getSubCatalogs(mainCatalog)
                    .observe(this@ActivityAddCatalogNames, { list ->
                        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
                            this@ActivityAddCatalogNames,
                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                            list
                        )

                        binding?.subspinnercatalog?.adapter = adapter
                    })


            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

        }
```

ViewModel code

```
  fun getSubCatalogs(mainCatalog:String): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> {
    var subCatalogs = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>>()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        subCatalogs = productDao.getSubCatalogs(mainCatalog)
    }
    return subCatalogs
}
```

repository code

```
   fun getSubCatalogs(mainCatalog: String): MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> {

    subCatalogCollection.whereEqualTo("mainCatalogtName", mainCatalog)
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
            if (e != null) {
                return@addSnapshotListener
            }
            if (snapshot != null) {
                val catalogs = ArrayList<String>()
                val documents = snapshot.documents
                documents.forEach {
                    val catalog = it.getString("subCatalogName")
                    if (catalog != null) {
                        catalogs.add(catalog)
                    }
                }
                _subCatalog.value = catalogs
            }
        }
    return _subCatalog
}
```

Comment: Why would you do `viewModelScope.launch` when the Firebase Library works asynchronously by default. You have no need to use a coroutine in this case. I think it would work without the `launch` part

Comment: my problem is not with the coroutines. the actual problem is in repository function return statements gets called before fetching the data so it is returning empty ist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my function that calls an API return an empty or null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Comment: Since you are using the Kotlin programming language, I think that this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getSubCatalogs` method works asynchronously and takes times to fetch data make it `suspend` and add this dependency to work firebase with coroutines:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1'
```

repository implementation would be :

```
    suspend fun getSubCatalogs(mainCatalog: String): MutableList<String> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO)  {
        return@withContext try{
            val dataSnapshot = subCatalogCollection.whereEqualTo("mainCatalogtName", mainCatalog).await()
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                val catalogs = mutableListOf<String>()
                val documents = dataSnapshot.documents
                documents.forEach {
                    val catalog = it.getString("subCatalogName")
                    if (catalog != null) {
                        catalogs.add(catalog)
                    }
                }
               catalogs
            }else emptyList<String>().toMutableList()
        }catch (e: Exception){
            emptyList<String>().toMutableList()
        }
    }
```

otherwise if you are going with kotlin flow then use [Callback Flow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow?hl=fr#callback)

Comment: @SagarDeshmukh you are welcome & does it helpful?